# How to decode repeatly incoming byte messages after a HTTP handler with Netty?

Tags: java, netty, icecast

I am using the feature of Icecast to add a repeatedly message containing the current metadata of the stream. It is enabled with following header:

```
request.headers().set("Icy-MetaData", "1");
```

After this, in the HTTP response there is a header containing the interval, which defines that the server sends metadata again after `x` bytes of the normal stream content. In addition, I want to store the stream content between the metadata tags.

My question is now, how is the best way to achieve this? One thaught was to use the `ByteToMessageDecoder` to "filter" the metadata tags, but the bytes were already decoded to an `HttpObject`. My current handler looks like this:

```
public class StreamClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpObject> {


    private int metadataInterval = 0;

    @Override
    protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext handlerContext, HttpObject message) throws Exception {

        if(message instanceof HttpResponse) {
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) message;
            this.metadataInterval = Integer.parseInt(response.headers().get("icy-metaint").toString());
        }

        if(message instanceof HttpContent) {

            HttpContent content = (HttpContent) message;



            if(content instanceof LastHttpContent) {
                // Close connection
                handlerContext.channel().close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!